# Get previous months date in year and month format

Tags: sql-server

What function can I use to get the previous months date in the format yyyy-mm .  This is what I have tried.

```
SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'yyyy-MM') as date
```

Comment: Ask the real question. Your tried something - why does that "something" not match your requirements? The real question is how to get a date - any date - in the prior month from the current date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use DATEADD:

```
SELECT FORMAT (DATEADD(mm, -1, getdate()), 'yyyy-MM') as date
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c86f614d4d0d126d83bdeae3f1303ac5)**